# Is there an Android Things kit that includes a gyroscope sensor?

Tags: android

I am looking to make an app that detects door movement (not with motion sensors, but with a gyroscope), but I want to use Android Things for this project. I've been looking around, but so far, I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Android Things only had the base kit. You'll have to buy and integrate any additional hardware components yourself.

For a gyroscope in an IoT project use something MPU6050 based:

like: [Adafruit MPU-6050 6-DoF Accel and Gyro Sensor - STEMMA QT Qwiic](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3886?gclid=CjwKCAjwm_P5BRAhEiwAwRzSO5dOI-q3QZscRaq2FAWKfBTd5pfXv6Q6s5qEx50BrR6x4PsJZYkTmBoCiacQAvD_BwE)